# "hdparm error: SG_IO: bad/missing sense data" while trying to unlock HDD using hdparm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, bios, passwords

I'm trying to unlock my password protected secondary storage(HDD) on Ubuntu 20.04 using the command:

`sudo hdparm --security-unlock "1" /dev/sda`

1 being the password I had set onto the drive in a different system (with a different version of BIOS) previously.

and doing that, I get the error:

> security_password: "1"

> /dev/sda:
> Issuing SECURITY_UNLOCK command, password="1", user=user

> SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Now, for reference, the output of:
`sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda`
before and after suspending my system(in order to **unfreeze** the drive) are:

Before (right after system startup):

```
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
        enabled
    not locked
        frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    Security level high
```

After (suspend):

```
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
        enabled
        locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    Security level high
```

As you can see that it is locked after the suspension; because of which, I am unable to access the contents of the drive, the problem that I am looking to get rid of.

Also, note that I am unable to *unset* the password via BIOS as the BIOS doesn't show it to be set. I also tried to set a new password via BIOS in hopes that it might *overwrite* the current password which I can remove; however, even after setting the admin and user password in BIOS, the **Set Drive Password** option, while available and highlighted, doesn't open any input console. So I was hoping I could either **remove the password**  or **manually unlock** it using `hdparm`.

The complete **SG_IO** of the above error is:

> SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Edit:

Additional information:

The system I'm using is lenovo ideapad gaming 3 15arh05.
Part of output of `hdparm -I`:

```
    Model Number:       ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB                        
    Firmware Revision:  2BA30001
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0028) 
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
```

It's connected internally via a ffc adapter/SATA cable - [5C10S30065 HDD Cable L 81Y4 HDD/B](https://download.lenovo.com/Images/Parts/5C10S30065/5C10S30065_A.jpg).

Comment: What are the computer and disk models and how is the disk connected to the computer, as in external/external, SCSI, SATA etc.

Comment: The system I'm using is **lenovo ideapad gaming 3 15arh05**. As for the model of hdd in question: ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB and it's connected internally via a ffc adapter/SATA cable - [5C10S30065 HDD Cable L 81Y4 HDD/B](https://download.lenovo.com/Images/Parts/5C10S30065/5C10S30065_A.jpg). I'll try to incorporate this and more info related to the HDD to my post but I'm afraid it'd become too long. Anyway, I'm grateful for the response.

Comment: As the BIOS on the new computer doesn't understand this locked disk, you might need to find a computer of the same model as the one where the password was set.

Comment: I suppose that'd be the easiest solution. I appreciate the help, @harrymc.

Comment: I'm afraid that's the only solution.

Comment: I've added an answer. If you consider it helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the BIOS on the new computer doesn't understand this locked disk,
you might need to find a computer of the same model as the one where the
password was set.